# prevent other android application to know flags status of my application (getRunningServices )

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to hide my app flags ( running status ) from another app?

For example there is app called "p1" and it have running service and there another app called "p2".
if i called getRunningServices in app "p2" then it will tell me if app "p1" running or not.

is there any way to prevent "p2" to know "p1" flags (running).

Answer (score 0):

No, for obvious security reasons. Malware authors, for example, would love to be able to hide their malware from anti-malware apps.